# PHP how to access database and make query using $db->*

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to access database and make query using
`$db->*` like `$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);` I've tried this before when i was
using codeigniter framework following this [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#preparing-the-query).

if i will use the standard PHP OOP the only way i can do it is:

```
class Database {
    function connect() {
        //PDO connection
    }
}
class Model extends Database {
    function connect() {
        $stmt = Database::connect()->prepare($sql);
        OR
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

or by using [PDO::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) this closes i can use is `$this->`:

```
class Database extends PDO {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(//PDO connection);
    }
}
class Model extends Database {
    function connect() {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

how to achieve this like in the codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using codeigniter so for connection with database go to cofig file in application folder and find the file name database.php. in this file write your database auths. then into model if you want to insert write $this->db->create($table name, $data),

Comment: no i'm not using codeigniter for this particular project but i wanted to achieve something that, actually on codeigniter you can omit `$this->` following the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#preparing-the-query)